# Let an administrator login as user

Tags: php, membership

I want to be able as an administrator to login as a user. At the moment, all my users need to enter their email and password to login. The password is encrypted with md5 and a salt key. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I have a service where users advertise their holiday homes. I want to login as user in order to correct some problematic info they enter. I can do this from the administration page, but I thought that logging as a user would be faster to edit.

Comment: This pretty much depends on how your login system is implemented. There are too many factors playing in this to give a good answer without knowing more about that

Comment: Why not create a regular user account for such things? Subverting your code to make it do "this is an admin but pretend they're a user" gets hideously ugly fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say build a page that is only accessible to administrators, and allows the user to change his uid in the session variable, or the cookie, or wherever you are storing that info.